# Run cron task on AWS EMR master node

Tags: amazon-web-services, cron, emr, amazon-emr

How can i run periodic job in background on EMR cluster? 
I have script.sh with cron job and application.py in s3 and want to run cluster with this command:

```
aws emr create-cluster 
--name "Test cluster"
–-release-label emr-5.12.0 
--applications Name=Hive Name=Pig Name=Ganglia Name=Spark
--use-default-roles 
--ec2-attributes KeyName=myKey 
--instance-type m3.xlarge 
--instance-count 3 
--steps Type=CUSTOM_JAR,Name=CustomJAR,ActionOnFailure=CONTINUE,
Jar=s3://region.elasticmapreduce/libs/script-runner/script-runner.jar,
Args["s3://mybucket/script-path/script.sh"]
```

Finally, i want that cron job from script.sh execute application.py 
Now i don't understand how to install cron on master node, python file need some libraries, they should be installed to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to SSH into the master node, and then perform the crontab setup from there, not on your local machine:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-connect-master-node-ssh.html

> **Connect to the Master Node Using SSH**
>
> Secure Shell (SSH) is a network protocol you can use to create a
>   secure connection to a remote computer. After you make a connection,
>   the terminal on your local computer behaves as if it is running on the
>   remote computer. Commands you issue locally run on the remote
>   computer, and the command output from the remote computer appears in
>   your terminal window.
>
> When you use SSH with AWS, you are connecting to an EC2 instance,
>   which is a virtual server running in the cloud. When working with
>   Amazon EMR, the most common use of SSH is to connect to the EC2
>   instance that is acting as the master node of the cluster.
>
> Using SSH to connect to the master node gives you the ability to
>   monitor and interact with the cluster. You can issue Linux commands on
>   the master node, run applications such as Hive and Pig interactively,
>   browse directories, read log files, and so on. You can also create a
>   tunnel in your SSH connection to view the web interfaces hosted on the
>   master node. For more information, see View Web Interfaces Hosted on
>   Amazon EMR Clusters.

Answer (score 0):

By default crontab is installed in linux system, you don't need to install manually.

To add spark job scheduling in cron, please follow below steps

- Login into master node (SSH into master).
- run command

> crontab -e

- Add the below line in crontab and save it ( :w)

  `*/15 0 * * * /script-path/script.sh`

  Now cron will schedule the jobs for every 15 minutes.

Please refer this [link](http://www.cronmaker.com/) to know about cron.

Hope this helps.

Thanks
Ravi

Comment: this command run contrab task on my PC, but i want run contrab task on master node in EMR

Comment: You need to SSH into master node and configure it.